# Why does wp_get_object_terms add a period after terms are output?

Tags: terms, taxonomy

I'm using the following line to output an unordered list of taxonomies and their associated terms for a custom post type. The only problem with it is that a period gets added after the term.

```
wp_get_object_terms( $id, the_taxonomies( 'before=<ul><li>&sep=</li><li>&after=</li></ul>' ) );
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
<ul><li>Taxname: <a href='http://site.com/taxname/taxterm/'>Taxterm</a>.</li></ul>
```

Is there an argument I can add to `wp_get_object_terms` to remove the period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wp_get_object_terms() isn't the problem. the_taxonomies() is doing the outputting; it doesn't return anything.

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
the_taxonomies( 'before=<ul><li>&sep=</li><li>&after=</li></ul>' );
wp_get_object_terms( $id, null );
```

Now, if you go to wp-includes/taxonomy.php you will find the dot in the_taxonomies() source.

To remove the dot, you need to add a filter:

```
function remove_the_dot($template) {
  return '%s: %l';
}
add_filter('taxonomy_template', 'remove_the_dot');
```

In case you're wondering, yes, this *is* an akward way of doing things.

In WP 3.1, you can modify the template simply by passing it as a parameter:

```
the_taxonomies( array(
  'before' => '<ul><li>',
  'sep' => '</li><li>',
  'after' => '</li></ul>',
  'template' => '%s: %l'
) );
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming this line (in `get_the_taxonomies`) is causing it? `$template = apply_filters('taxonomy_template', '%s: %l.');`

If so, is there a good way to do this and avoid the periods?

Comment: Yes, it's just under your nose: the 'taxonomy_template' filter. See updated answer.